# python как задать неравенство двух рандомных чисел? assert тут не работает

Tags: python

```
r1 = random.randrange(1,6,1)
r2 = random.randrange(1,6,1)
team_home, team_away = '', ''
rr = (r1, r2)
for r in rr:
    assert r1 != r2



AssertionError:
```

Что делать?

Comment: так тоже не работает: assert r1 != r2

Comment: А при чём здесь `assert` вообще? У вас какая задача - получить два разных случайных числа?

Comment: 'получить два разных случайных числа' - да

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В модуле `random` есть специальная функция для этого.

```
r1, r2 = random.sample(range(1,6), k=2)
```

Comment: Точно, опять забыл про `sample`, и поиск главное ничего не подсказал ))

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите получить два (или сколько хотите) заведомо разных рандомных числа из определённого диапазона, предлагаю вам такой рецепт:

```
import random

r = list(range(1, 6))
random.shuffle(r)
r1, r2 = r[:2]
print(r1, r2)
```

Т.е. делаем список чисел нужного диапазона, перемешиваем его случайным образом, и берём из него нужное кол-во чисел, например, с начала списка.

`assert` же используется совсем не для этого, обычно его используют в тестах, чтобы проверить, что написанная вами функция работает правильно.